# dataset parameter in forms app

Tags: vb.net, parameters, dataset, adapter

I'm having a hard time to find out how to pass at run time a parameter which I defined in an adapter in a dataset. When I preview the data I can insert the value manually, but I was not able to find any code around how to pass it in the visual basic code.
Any help will be appreciated ;-)
Thanks in advance for your help
Georges-Louis

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize you mentioned Forms.

Have you tried creating a Public Function method with attributes? Maybe I'm not clear on the question, but you mean you have a defined value for your dataapapter, then you want to change it at run time, is this correct? Do you have that value as a variable?

Comment: hi Extofer, thanks for your help. I created a dataset, with an adapter, which has a '@param1' in the where clause. When I test it in the preview I get the parameter as a manual input, which works fine. The only point is that I do not know how you can pass this parameter in the code. I just found ways to do it when you code the whole connection info and sql in the code, otherwise I know it only in asp.net (I use a session, which can be passed to the adapter). Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: hi, it worked with: Private Sub frmReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    ' strParam is your parameter to pass to the query 
    Me.dtReportTableAdapter.FillByDate(Me.DataSet1.dtReport, strParam) 
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport() 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function that fills the TableAdapter you can specify the parameter to pass to the query or stored procedure.

```
Private Sub frmReport_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' strParam is your parameter to pass to the query
    Me.dtReportTableAdapter.FillByDate(Me.DataSet1.dtReport, strParam)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

I hope this helps.